# How to add Common property to two classes that derive from EventArgs?

Tags: c#, .net, code-reuse

Say I have this classes that derived from EventArgs

```
public class myclass01:EventArgs
{
  public string channel{get;set;}
  public string generic_property{get;set;}
}

public class myclass02:EventArgs
{
  public string extension{get;set;}
  public string generic_property{get;set;}
}
```

How can I make it so that I don't have to define `"generic_property"` over and over again on classes that derived from `EventArgs`? Sort of like I will have a base class that has all my generic properties.

Comment: Simply add a base class that derive form eventargs and have the property and derive form it.

Comment: One of these days C# might get "Traits" but .. not today. As such, *only* subclassing allows "direct implementation sharing" (there are ways to proxy types and/or use composition, they just don't apply here). See projects like [NRoles](https://code.google.com/p/nroles/), which is a post-compilation transform. YMMV.

Comment: Side note: consider not adding thank you notes to your posts. Discuss on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) if needed, but check [thank you removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) discussion first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a class that is derived from `EventArgs`, which you use as the base for all your custom classes.  This class should be `abstract` if you don't want it to be useable directly.

```
public abstract class MyCommonEventBase : EventArgs
{
  public string generic_property { get; set; }
}

public class myclass01 : MyCommonEventBase
{
  public string channel{get;set;}
}

public class myclass02 : MyCommonEventBase
{
  public string extension{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: It's too bad C# doesn't have extension properties. Then there'd be no need for inheritance. Think Objective-C's categories. :)